# OpenGL glTranslatef not working as it should

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

So I decided to make a 3D Stars kinda thing in C++ with SDL and OpenGL. I created a Point class which holds x, y, and z values. I create an array of Points and fill it with random coordinates. This seems to work but when I do glTranslatef(0,0,0.1f) or something similar, the stars don't come close, they just disappear.

```
//OpenGL Initialization Code
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(30.0f,640.0/480.0,0.3f,500.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//Random point generation
for(int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
{
   float randomX = (float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/100.0f) - 50.0f;
   float randomY = (float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/20) - 10.0f;
   float randomZ = (float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/20) - 20.0f;
   points[i] = Point(randomX, randomY,randomZ);
}

//Render
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for(int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
{
   glVertex3f(points[i]._x, points[i]._y, points[i]._z);
}
glEnd();
glTranslatef(0,0,0.1f);
SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
SDL_Flip(screen);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *stars dont come close* What does this mean? Are you expecting them to appear larger? Do they all disappear immediately, or do they disappear one at a time?

Comment: They disappear one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the OpenGL initialization code after the code where I init SDL SetVideoMode, it works as it should now.

Answer (score 2):

Is that code your render function?

If it is, then you should move the point generation elsewhere so that they get generated only once.

If it is not, then you should move the initialization code to the beginning of the render function. The matrices should be cleared every frame.

If that doesn't work:

Try temporarily disabling depth testing. If they don't disappear and you see lines, you need to adjust your view frustum. Try using gluLookAt

Also, try translating them in the negative z axis. If I remember correctly, in opengl, object-space coordinates are farther away as z decreases. (0 is closer than -1)

Comment: It's not, I trimmed the code. Apparently the problem was I called the initOpenGL function BEFORE I created the SDL Screen. I moved it just before where the loop starts and it works now. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why they'ld be disappearing, but in your sample code it should be inert.  You load a new Identity matrix at the top for the MODELVIEW matrix, and then translate it *after* you've rendered.  Try moving the glTranslate to right before your glBegin.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. http://www.mediafire.com/?2cm3v3m1nvzcbnb Here's the whole source, I'd really appreciate if you take a look at it.